# Citation with additional information for multiple references

Tags: cross-referencing, citing, natbib

I would like to produce a citation which looks something like this:

(mammals: Ginsberg and Huck 1989; birds: Griffith et al. 2002; fishes: Avise et al. 2002)

If I had a single reference I know I could do this:

```
\citep[mammals:][]{Ginsburg1989}
```

Is there any way of adding additional information for each reference?

Answer (score 2):

I can propose a `\multicitep` command:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{ginsburg1989,
  author={Ginsburg, X. and Huck, Y.},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=1989,
}
@article{griffith2002,
  author={Griffith, X. and Abc, Y. and Def, Z.},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2002,
}
@article{avise2002,
  author={Avise, X. and Abc, Y. and Def, Z.},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2002,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__lara_ccitep_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\multicitep}{m}
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__lara_ccitep_seq
  (
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__lara_ccitep_seq { \citenop ##1 }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__lara_ccitep_seq { ;~ }
  )
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\citenop}{om}
 {
  \IfValueT{#1}{#1~}
  \citeauthor{#2},\nobreakspace\citeyear{#2}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\multicitep{[mammals:]{ginsburg1989},[birds:]{griffith2002},[fish:]{avise2002}}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is used just to make the example self-contained. Use your own database.

[image]

Comment: That is excellent, thank you. In some cases, I do not want the first reference to have any extra information. For example, I can use your new command: \multicitep{[]{Ginsburg1989,Avise2002},[but see]{Griffith2002}}, however this creates a space infront of the first reference. How would I change it to prevent this?

Comment: @Lara You can do `\multicitep{{ginsburg1989},{avise2002},[but see]{griffith2002}}`

Comment: This: \multicitep{{Ginsburg1989},{Avise2002}} gives warnings "Package natbib Warning: Citation `G' on page 56 undefined on input line 119." and prints as: (?, ?insburg1989; ?, ?vise2002). Any advise?